# AndEngine Smooth Rotation along Path

Tags: android, andengine

I am drawing a path and move a sprite along it. Now i want the sprite to always look into the driving direction after each waypoint.
With this Code i can just set the Direction(non smooth). getTargetAngle returns the new rotation angle.

```
float angleDeg = getTargetAngle(sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(), targetX[pWaypointIndex + 1], targetY[pWaypointIndex + 1]);
sprite.setRotation(angleDeg);
```

Now i can do it smooth, except im at the turning point from -179° to 179°, where it turns along the long-path instead of the short and makes a jump:

```
sprite.unregisterEntityModifier(rotMod);
rotMod = new RotationModifier(0.5f, currentAngleDeg, angleDeg);
sprite.registerEntityModifier(rotMod);
```

I tried adding/subbing 360° to the current angle of the sprite when the absolute addition of both Angles exceeds 180°. Making the jump from -179° to 179° to a jump from 181 to 179, but this doesnt work.

```
if(Math.abs((float)angleDeg) + Math.abs((float)currentAngleDeg) > 180) {
if (currentAngleDeg < 0) {
    currentAngleDeg+=360.0f;
} else {
    currentAngleDeg-=360.0f;
}
```

getTargetAngle:

```
public float getTargetAngle(float startX, float startY, float         targetX, float targetY){

    float dX = targetX - startX;
    float dY = targetY - startY;
    float angleRad = (float) Math.atan2(dY, dX);
    float angleDeg = (float) Math.toDegrees(angleRad);
    return angleDeg;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Could you show the code for getTargetAngle() please? If I call .registerEntityModifier(new RotationModifier(0.5f, 181.0f, 179.0f)), it rotates as I suspect you require, anticlockwise by 2°, is this the same in your case, i.e., if it is hard coded this way?

Comment: added the Code in question

Comment: Did the code below sort this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the rotation is always relative to the scene's axis orientation. The angle given by the function getTargetAngle() needs to be with respect to the current rotation of the sprite.

Please try the following,

Remove the adding/subbing 360° code, then replace your getTargetAngle() function with the following,

```
public float getTargetAngle(float startX, float startY, float startAngle, float targetX, float targetY){

    float dX = targetX - startX;
    float dY = targetY - startY;

    //find the coordinates of the waypoint in respect to the centre of the sprite
    //with the scene virtually rotated so that the sprite is pointing at 0°

    float cos = (float) Math.cos( Math.toRadians(-startAngle));
    float sin = (float) Math.sin( Math.toRadians(-startAngle));

    float RotateddX = ((dX * cos) - (dY * sin));
    float RotateddY = ((dX * sin) + (dY * cos));

    //Now get the angle between the direction the sprite is pointing and the
    //waypoint
    float angleRad = (float) Math.atan2(RotateddY, RotateddX);

    float angleDeg = (float) Math.toDegrees(angleRad);
    return angleDeg;
}
```

Then when you reach the waypoint,

```
sprite.unregisterEntityModifier(rotMod);
float angleDeg = getTargetAngle(sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(), sprite.getRotation(), targetX[pWaypointIndex + 1], targetY[pWaypointIndex + 1]);
rotMod = new RotationModifier(0.5f, sprite.getRotation(), sprite.getRotation() + angleDeg);
sprite.registerEntityModifier(rotMod);
```

Note that the rotation modifier adds the return value from getTargetAngle() on to the existing sprite rotation - It is now an angle with respect to the existing angle.

The rotation will always occur in the direction of the angle <= 180° be it clockwise or anticlockwise.